# Mongoose - Referencing another model using require

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

What I'm trying to do is to update one collection, Prize, and then based on the result from that update another collection, League.

I have the following code:

```
app.post('/auth/prize/:prizeId', function(req, res) {
    console.log('POST /auth/prize/' + req.params.prizeId);
    if (req.user) {
        var mess = 'JOINED';
        var query = {...};
        var update = {...};
        Prize.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function(err, result) {
            if (err || result === null) {
                mess = 'ERROR Incorrect password';
                res.send(mess);
                return;
            }
            var League = require('./leagues_api');
            var queryL = {...};
            var updateL = {...};
            League.findOneAndUpdate(queryL, updateL, function(e, r) {
                if (e || r === null) {
                    mess = 'ERROR Incorrect password';
                }
                res.send(mess);
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.send(401, 'Not Admin!');
    }
});
```

So, the issue is that I am seeing an error:

```
[TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findOneAndUpdate']
```

I have two separate files to keep everything easy to manage, so I have this file, prizes_api.js, and another file, leages_api.js, which has defined it in the Schema and the Model for League:

```
var leagueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});
var League = mongoose.model('League', leagueSchema);
```

I use this same style elsewhere, but for some reason in this file I am seeing the error failure. Any advice on this please?

Thank you, Gary.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something simple... (You can repost as an answer so I can accept). I added to leagues_api `exports = module.exports = League;` to get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling `require('./leagues_api')` isn't returning the `League` model, then your `module.exports` isn't set up right in that file.

It should look like the following:

```
module.exports = League;
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add this part in.
For my setup, I add:
`exports = module.exports = League;`
to the bottom of the leagues_api.js (before the final `}`).

Comment: Glad it helped. You don't need the `exports = ` part. See [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html) for the details.

Comment: Right you are, thanks, will update my other code to reflect this.